# Sentry: express api basic auth middleware make sentry unable to work

Tags: node.js, express, middleware, sentry

I have a nodeJs express router, using `@sentry/node`, that is able to send errors with Sentry.captureException only before i add a basic auth middleware using:

```
import auth from 'http-auth';

let basic = auth.basic(
    { realm: "api that dispatch requests.." }, 
    (username, password, callback) => {
        callback(username === vars.username && password === vars.password); 
    }
);

app.use(auth.connect(basic));
```

If i define my POST route after this code, i get:

```
Sentry Logger [Error]: 'beforeSend' threw an error, will not send event.
```

I can’t remove my BasicAuth, and find extremely important to be able to report exceptions in my authenticated routes…

Thanks for any help,

Victor

Comment: How does your Sentry code look like? What are you doing in the `beforeSend` callback?

Comment: @HazA i did not add a specific `beforeSend` callback that's why i'm unable to really understand what should i do..

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to use the express integration, you can simply

```
new Sentry.NodeClient(config)
```